# Grades of vertex in graph in Prolog

Tags: prolog

edge is a :- dynamic edge/2

the edge indicates only if the vertex are joined, example:

```
edge(a, b). 
edge(c, d). 
edge(r, c). 
edge(c, t). 
edge(a, t).
```

And I want to know if a vertex have 3 or more edges but only one of them, if there are more than one with 3 or more should return no.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In SWI Prolog:

```
test() :-
  findall([A,B], edge(A,B), VRaw),        % find every vertex.
  flatten(VRaw, VFlat),                   % make a flat list of them.
  msort(VFlat, VSorted),                  % sort them.
  clumped(VSorted, VClumped),             % count how many of each.
  include([_-C]>>(C>=3), VClumped, V3),   % filter the ones with count>=3.
  length(V3, 1).                          % was there exactly one?
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
unique_vertex_with_three_or_more_edges(V) :-
    setof(V, vertex_with_three_or_more_edges(V), [V]).

vertex_with_three_or_more_edges(V) :-
    setof(W, (edge(V,W) ; edge(W,V)), [_,_,_|_]).
```

Example:

```
?- time(unique_vertex_with_three_or_more_edges(X)).
% 78 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = c.

?- time(unique_vertex_with_three_or_more_edges(c)).
% 35 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
true.

?- time(unique_vertex_with_three_or_more_edges(a)).
% 33 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
false.
```